# Will interrupting a galaxybase-load request when using the import tool galaxybase-load affect the graph being imported?

Tags: graph-databases

I am using Galaxybase graph database and the import tool galaxybase-load to import graphs. If I interrupt the galaxybase-load request, will it affect the graph that is being imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, galaxybase-load supports interrupting graph importing tasks by sending requests. After interruption, no data will be imported to the graph project, and galaxybase-load does not support pausing or resuming graph importing tasks. Only full termination is possible.

Since the question is unclear, there is another situation: if you lose access to ssh on the client side, it will not affect the graph importing task. Galaxybase-load is only used to initiate import requests and obtain import progress. The actual import task is performed by the graph service backend. If the ssh connection of galaxybase-load is interrupted, it will only prevent further printing of the import progress and will not affect the import task on the server side.

Comment: What should I do if I want to terminate the import while using galaxybase-load to import data?

Comment: You can send a GET request ```${ip}:18088/api/buildGraph/stop?graphName={graph name}``` to terminate the import.